# CXF: Custom LoggingOutInterceptor is not triggered

Tags: spring-boot, logging, configuration, cxf

Want to mask some response fields coming from 3 party APi hence created a custom interceptor extending the loggingOutInterceptor but its not being triggered. As want to convert some data as *** before being log to console

Here is the CXF.xml file

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:cxf="http://cxf.apache.org/core"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://cxf.apache.org/core http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/core.xsd">

    <bean id="MyLogging" class="com.abc.abc.abc.service.util.MyLogging"/>

    <!-- We are adding the interceptors to the bus as we will have only one endpoint/service/bus. -->

    <cxf:bus>
        <cxf:inInterceptors>
            <ref bean="MyLogging"/>
        </cxf:inInterceptors>
        <cxf:outInterceptors>
            <ref bean="MyLogging"/>
        </cxf:outInterceptors>
    </cxf:bus>
</beans>

and My custom interceptor code is

@Component
public class MyLogging extends LoggingOutInterceptor {

@Overide
 public void handleMessage(Message message) throws Fault{
//some code

}
}
```

Could you please help me on this if any other configuration needed. I need to mask some sensitive data coming from 3 party API response.